# Need help on crank setup for Gravel bike!

Tags: gravel, newbie, gearing

I've been cycling for about a year and a half now (yes, I'm a newbie) and I'm very happy with it! I currently have a Merida gravel bike with a GRX 600 crankset (46/30) and 10-speed GRX 400 FD with 11 - 36T cassette. I'm considering getting a power meter from XCadey that has a 50/34 crankset. My question is, will this setup work on my existing bike, and will I need to make any adjustments (e.g. change the chain) for it to work? I'm an average biker but love to have the speed on the road without sacrificing the ability to climb steep hills. Unsure if the gear ratio with this new setup will work.

Comment: Changing the crank will raise every gear about one step.  You will lose your lowest gear and get a new one above your current top.  That may be good or may be bad, but it is worth considering.

Comment: What model is the proposed replacement? The GRX crank has a special chainline IIRC, so you may not be able to blindly replace it with say a 105 crank or something.

Comment: Appreciate the response! I had a bike fit recently and the guy suggested I swap out my 170mm crankset for a 160mm as the Merida gravel bike I purchased, despite getting an XS size, was too long for (Top Tube). Here's the website: https://xcadey.com/xpower-crankset/ . I couldn't find a compatible crank arm but someone suggested about the XCadey power meter as an option. That's why I'm looking into getting it.

Comment: You definitely will sacrifice your low gears. One of my main motivations for replacing 50/34 for GRX on my bike was to get those low gears that are necessary in the terrain and with baggage.

Comment: Is your main motivation to change the crank arm length?

Comment: that's correct since this was the advice of my bike fitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can fit that crankset on your bike without it rubbing on the chainstay, and the front derailleur can be moved up to cope with the larger rings, then you will loose the lowest of your low gears but gain some higher ones.

Yes you will need a longer chain, so its probably time for a new cassette too.

Your 30:36 low gear is 22.5 gear-inches, and changing to a 34:36 is 27.0 gear inches.

Your high gear of 46:11 is 112 and 50:11 is 132 gear inches - less of a gap but still significant.

---

To put that more graphically, here are your gears:

[image]
 <sub>Image is sourced from https://www.gear-calculator.com/?GR=DERS&KB=24 - just have to go into Settings and increase the maximum number of chainrings from 3.  Very handy tool.</sub>

Blue is your current set, and Red is your proposed set.   Green shows that your current "second largest" cog will be about the same as your new largest cog gearing, so if you can ride in that and not feel the need to go to an easier gear, then you don't need it.

Same at the top end - your current 46:11 gear is close enough to 50:12, and then there's 50:11 above that.

In other words **YES** you sacrifice a low gear and gain an additional high gear.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate the reply. To your point. I need to check and ensure first that the crankset will fit without rubbing the chainstay and not cause any issues with the FD.